# Mysql improve performance of count with join

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join

I need to improve a query similar to the following which simply performs a count based on some filtering while also joining a second table. The books table could have million of records.

```
CREATE TABLE author
    (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(20), style varchar(20));


CREATE TABLE books
(
    id int auto_increment primary key not null,
    author_id int not null, 
    title varchar(20) not null, 
    level int not null, 
    date datetime not null, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_author FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(id)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_level_date ON books(level, date);

INSERT INTO author
    (name, style)
VALUES
    ('John', 'Fact'),
    ('Sarah', 'Fact'),
    ('Michael', 'Fiction');


INSERT INTO books
    (id, author_id, title, level, date)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'John Book 1', 1, '2012-01-13 13:10:30'),
    (2, 1, 'John Book 2', 1, '2011-03-12 12:10:20'),
    (3, 1, 'John Book 3', 2, '2012-01-23 12:40:30'),
    (4, 2, 'Sarah Book 1', 1, '2009-10-15 13:10:30'),
    (5, 2, 'Sarah Book 2', 2, '2013-01-30 12:10:30'),
    (6, 3, 'Michael Book 1', 3, '2012-11-13 12:10:30');
```

It runs extremely quickly once I remove the **join** but I really need the join in there as I may need to filter based on the author table.

Can anyone help by suggesting potentially more indexing that could help speed things up.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Can we have the whole picture please? I.e. If you have indexes, can we see what they are and how you've defined them?

Comment: @MatW I think we can see the indexes !??!?!

Comment: @Strawberry I meant the composite index mentioned, rather than the primary key we can see

Comment: Indexing anything other than (b.author_id,b.date)  won't be useful (for this specific query)

Comment: (I was talking to dre)

Comment: just a design flaw to mention, books often have multiple authors, this design will nto work when that happens.

Comment: I doubt that this is a real scenario. ;-)

Comment: Hi all. Thats for considering my question. What is in the question is just an example of a more complicated couple of tables that I have the issue with. I just wanted to keep it simple but the idea is the same. The `id` columns are primary keys and `author_id` in books is a foreign key. I'll edit this question again for clarity.

Comment: We can't tell what is wrong with your query without actually seeing the query.

Comment: Question is now edited. Anyone have any suggestions on how to format an "explain" result set for this page?

Answer (score 1):

You always need to index foreign key fields as well as primary key fields.

Comment: +1 but it's worse than that. He has `author_id` as a foreign key without even defining it as such.

Comment: The example I've given is not the real query, just an example. You can take it that there is a foreign key relationship on `author_id` as stated in the question.

Comment: HOwever an Fk does not mean there is an index

Comment: I think it does as I use the innoDB storage engine.